# See how a file is changed on current branch compared to develop branch

Tags: git, git-diff

I have two branches.

- **feature/sidebar**
- **develop**

I am currently on **feature/sidebar** and have nothing unstaged. All the changes that I had, have been committed. In other words, when I run `git status` I get:

> nothing to commit, working tree clean.

On **feature/sidebar** one of the files I changed is `index.html`. Using my defined `difftool` how can I see a list of the changes between `index.html` on **feature/sidebar** and `index.html` on **develop**?

Comment: Didn't you mean to start last paragraph with "On **develop** one of the files I changed..."?

Comment: No? the file has been changed on **feature/sidebar** and is committed there.

Comment: Oh sorry, very well then. Bad assumption on my part, let's forget it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you want to compare the current state of the working tree to its last commited state with

```
git difftool -- index.html
```

...or compare the staged changes with last commit :

```
git difftool --staged -- index.html
```

...but all this happens within the same branch.

To compare branches together, then explicitly list them (but this will compare their last commited state, not the index or working tree) :

```
git difftool develop feature/sidebar -- index.html
```

Comment: I share your thanks with padawin who had it too :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you run:

```
git diff develop feature/sidebar index.html
```

It will display the diff in your terminal.

If you want to use your difftool (e.g. Vim), you can run:

```
git difftool develop feature/sidebar index.html
```

Git will create 2 temporary files (one for each version) and open them in your difftool.